# Boto3: trying to add launch permission to AMI for an organizational unit raises ParamValidationError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-sam

Following the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/organizations.html#Organizations.Client.describe_organizational_unit) of boto3 ec2, I'm trying to extend the launch permissions of a custom built AMI to allow an organizational unit.

```
arns = [string list of arns]
for arn in arns:
        r = ec2.modify_image_attribute(
            ImageId=image['ImageId'],
            LaunchPermission={
                'Add': [
                    {
                        'OrganizationalUnitArn': arn
                    },
                ],
            }
        )
```

Running the above code I get the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in LaunchPermission.Add[0]: "OrganizationalUnitArn", must be one of: Group, UserId
```

The ARN is supplied as a string, and the code itself was directly copied from the documentation.
What's causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My local boto3 package was simply outdated, upgrading it fixed the problem.

Comment: Yes, that's a new-ish feature added a few months ago, so older boto3 sdks did not have it.

Comment: Can you please mention which version ? it is failing for me even with boto3 version 1.24.9

Comment: The same happening when working with this same piece of code on lambda function, Any other work around for this?

Comment: Currently on 1.27.30